# I need help Hashing passwords in Java

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql

So, my program works fine for registering and logging in with the info saved in the Database. 
I have little knowledge of coding as you can tell, in fact, It took me a week to write this simple piece of code...

Now, the reason why I made this post is because I need help with the hashing part, I'm stuck and still can't understand this part even though I've watched multiple videos and visited similar questions.

All I want to do is to save the user entered password from the Registering form to my Database (hashed or encrypted), and then log in with the normal password, by comparing it to the hashed one in the database (the hashing or encrypting method used doesn't matter). This is the last thing I have to add to my homework project, the thing is that my teacher hasn't taught us anything, and I'm learning by myself with the help of this site and youtube.

I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
    package sistemaricardo;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
 *
 * @author Ricardo
 */
public class RegisterForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement pst=null;
ResultSet rs = null;

    /**
     * Creates new form RegisterForm
     */
    public RegisterForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        registrar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        user = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        password = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();



    private void registrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:


        String uname = user.getText();
        String pass = String.valueOf(password.getPassword());


        if(uname.equals(""))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Add username");
        }

        else if(pass.equals(""))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Add password");
        }




        else{




        PreparedStatement ps = null;


        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sistemaricardo?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC","root","");
            String query = "INSERT INTO `multiuserlogin`(`username`, `password`,`usertype`) VALUES (?,?,?)";


            pst=con.prepareStatement(query);
pst.setString(1, user.getText());
pst.setString(2, password.getText());
pst.setString(3, String.valueOf(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()));
pst.executeUpdate();



            logindatabase lgf = new logindatabase();
        lgf.setVisible(true);
        lgf.pack();
        lgf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        lgf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.dispose();



        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegisterForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
        }
    }                                         





    private void userActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    private void passwordActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        


    private void jLabel5MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        logindatabase lgf = new logindatabase();
        lgf.setVisible(true);
        lgf.pack();
        lgf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        lgf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.dispose();
    }                                    



    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField password;
    private javax.swing.JButton registrar;
    private javax.swing.JTextField user;
    // End of variables declaration                   


}
```

Most of the examples like this one manually use a predefined password, I need to use the password entered by the user:

```
   require_once("password.php"); 
$password = "HelloStackOverflow"; 
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT); 
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 10)); 
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) { 
    /* Valid */
} else {
    /* Invalid */
}
```

Comment: Your first code block is in Java, second in PHP and you also tagged Javascript. What exactly are you using? Also you mentioned registering works, so before you save the password you receive from registration form into the database use the hash function on it.

Comment: $password is in plain text, $hash is a password hash. They can't be the same (ok they can but not likely). You must store the password in a hash too and copare passwordhash vs hash

Comment: @Andreas No you don't. The `password_verify()` method takes a plaintext password and a hash as arguments and compares them. You don't hash the password you want to check.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the code, but I thought $password was the representation of what the password is in the database